# How do I get device type information during the Detox test (react native)?

Tags: react-native, detox

Inside my test I have something like:

```
  console.log('Device id', device.id);
  console.log('Device name', device.name);
```

My output (when physical Android device connected):

```
detox[16444] INFO:  at e2e\firstTest.e2e.js:99:11
 Device id R9WN50QT4CJ
detox[16444] INFO:  at e2e\firstTest.e2e.js:100:11
 Device name R9WN50QT4CJ
```

I have the latest version of Detox. I am able to reproduce with an emulator (Pixel 2 android studio). With an emulator device id and device name were the same too.